# in django, let me know drop- down list

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-templates

i want to make nationality drop down list
i know how to make it, the problem is the number of nationality is over 100... 
i do not think i can type all nationalities...

can you help me..?
here is my model

```
Nationality_CHOICES = (
    ('AFGHANS', 'Afghans'),
    ('ALBANIANS', 'Albanians'),
   ......
)
class Student(models.Model):


 Nationality = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                  choices=Nationality_CHOICES,
                                  null = False)
```

> > here is all the nationalities :

Afghans
Albanians
Algerians
Americans
Andorrans
Angolans
Argentines
Armenians
Aromanians
Arubans
Australians
Austrians
Azerbaijanis
Bahamians
Bahrainis
Bangladeshis
Barbadians
Basotho
Basques
Belarusians
Belgians
Belizeans
Bermudians
Boers
Bosniaks
Brazilians
Bretons
British
British Virgin Islanders
Bruneians
Bulgarians
Macedonian Bulgarians
Burkinabès
Burundians
Cambodians
Cameroonians
Canadians
Catalans
Cape Verdeans
Chadians
Chileans
Chinese
Colombians
Comorians
Congolese
Croatians
Cubans
Cypriots
Turkish Cypriots
Czechs
Danes
Dominicans (Republic)
Dominicans (Commonwealth)
Dutch
East Timorese
Ecuadorians
Egyptians
Emiratis
English
Eritreans
Estonians
Ethiopians
Falkland Islanders
Faroese
Finns
Finnish Swedish
Fijians
Filipinos
French citizens
Georgians
Germans
Baltic Germans
Ghanaians
Gibraltar
Greeks
Greek Macedonians
Grenadians
Guatemalans
Guianese (French)
Guineans
Guinea-Bissau nationals
Guyanese
Haitians
Hondurans
Hong Kong
Hungarians
Icelanders
I-Kiribati
Indians
Indonesians
Iranians
Iraqis
Irish
Israelis
Italians
Ivoirians
Jamaicans
Japanese
Jordanians
Kazakhs
Kenyans
Koreans
Kosovars
Kurds
Kuwaitis
Kyrgyzs
Lao
Latvians
Lebanese
Liberians
Libyans
Liechtensteiners
Lithuanians
Luxembourgers
Macao
Macedonians
Malagasy
Malaysians
Malawians
Maldivians
Malians
Maltese
Manx
Mauritians
Mexicans
Moldovans
Moroccans
Mongolians
Montenegrins
Namibians
Nepalese
New Zealanders
Nicaraguans
Nigeriens
Nigerians
Norwegians
Pakistanis
Palauans
Palestinians
Panamanians
Papua New Guineans
Paraguayans
Peruvians
Poles
Portuguese
Puerto Ricans
Quebecers
Réunionnais
Romanians
Russians
Baltic Russians
Rwandans
Salvadorans
São Tomé and Príncipe
Saudis
Scots
Senegalese
Serbs
Sierra Leoneans
Singaporeans
Sindhian
Slovaks
Slovenes
Somalis
Somalilanders
South Africans
Spaniards
Sri Lankans
St Lucians
Sudanese
Surinamese
Swedes
Swiss
Syriacs
Syrians
Tajik
Taiwanese
Tanzanians
Thais
Tibetans
Tobagonians
Trinidadians
Tunisians
Turks
Tuvaluans
Ugandans
Ukrainians
Uruguayans
Uzbeks
Vanuatuans
Venezuelans
Vietnamese
Welsh
Yemenis
Zambians
Zimbabweans
Assyrians
Azeris
Basques
Bengalis
Berbers
Boers
Buryats
Cajuns
Catalans
Celts
Chuvash
Greeks
Han Chinese
Hispanic and Latino Americans
Hutus
Igbo
Indigenous Australians
Indigenous people of the Americas
First Nations
Huaorani people
Inuit
Canadian Inuit
Greenlandic Inuit
Métis people
Native Americans
Japanese
Karen
Kodavas
Kurds
Macedonians
Malays
Mongolians
Roma
Samis
Sikhs
Silesians
Sinhalese
Syriacs
Kannadigas
Tamils
Tatars
Tutsis
Zulus

> > here all language 
> >     Abaza

Abenaki

Abkhaz

Acehnese

Acholi

Achuar-Shiwiar

Adyghe

Adzera

Afaan Oromo

Afar

Afrikaans

Aghul

Aguacateco

Ainu

Ajië

Akan

Akhvakh

Akkadian

Aklan

Akurio

Alabama

Albanian

Aleut

Algonquin

Alsatian

Altay

Amarakaeri

Alur

Amharic

Amis

Andi

Anutan

Apache

Arabela

Arabic (Algerian)

Arabic (Egyptian)

Arabic (Lebanese)

Arabic (Modern Standard)

Arabic (Moroccan)

Arabic (Syrian)

Aragonese

Aramaic (Ancient)

Aramaic (Syriac)

Aramaic (Neo-)

Aranese

Arapaho

Arbëresh

Archi

Argobba

Armenian

Aromanian (Vlach)

Arrernte

Arvanitic

Asháninka

Assamese

(Neo-)Assyrian

Asturian

Atayal

Atikamekw

Avar

Avestan

Awngi

Aymara

Äynu

Azerbaijani

Babine-Witsuwit'en

Badaga

Bagatha

Bagvalal

Balinese

Balkar (Karachay-Balkar)

Baluchi

Bambara

Baniwa

Bantawa

Bartangi

Bashkir

Basque

Bassa

Batak Dairi

Batak Karo

Batak Mandailing

Batak Simalungun

Batak Toba

Bats

Bavarian

Bavarian (Central)

Bavarian (Northern)

Bavarian (Southern)

Beaver

Beja

Belarusian

Bemba

Bench

Bengali

Berber

Bhojpuri

Bikol/Bicol

Bima

Bislama

Blackfoot

Blin

Bodo

Bolinao

Bora

Bosnian

Botlikh

Bouyei

Breton

Budukh

Buginese

Buhid

Bulgarian

Bundjalung

Burmese

Burushaski

Buryat

Bushi

Carrier

Catalan

Cayuga

Cebuano

Chagatai
Chaha

Chamorro

Chechen

Cherokee

Cheyenne

Chichewa

Chickasaw

Chinese

Chinese
(Cantonese)

Chinese
(Dungan)

Chinese
(Gan)

Chinese
(Hakka)

Chinese
(Mandarin)

Chinese
(Shanghainese)

Chinese
(Taiwanese)

Chinese
(Teochew)

Chinese
(Xiang)

Chipewyan

Choctaw

Comanche

Cornish

Corsican

Cree

Creek

Croatian

Czech

Dakota

Dangme
Danish

Dargwa

Dari

Dinka

Dungan

Dutch

Dzongkha / Bhutanese

English (Old) / Anglo-Saxon

Erzya

Estonian

Esperanto

Ewe

Eyak

Faroese

Fijian

Finnish

Flemish

Fon

French

Frisian (North)

Frisian (West)

Friulan

Fula

Ga

Galician

Ganda

Ge'ez

Genoese

Georgian

German

Godoberi

Gooniyandi

Greek

Greenlandic

Guernsey Norman

Guarani

Gujarati

Gwich'in

Haida

Haitian Creole

Hän

Harari

Hausa

Hawaiian

Hebrew

Herero

Hindi

Hungarian

Icelandic

Igbo

Ilocano

Indonesian

Ingush

Inuktitut

Iñupiaq

Irish (Gaelic)

Italian

Japanese

Javanese

Jersey Norman

Kabardian

Kabyle

Kaingang

Kannada

Kanuri

Kapampangan

Karakalpak

Karelian

Kashmiri

Kashubian

Kazakh

Khakas

Khmer

Khoekhoe

Kikuyu

Kinyarwanda

Kiribati

Kirundi

Komi

Kongo

Konkani

Korean

Kumyk

Kurdish

Kven

Kwanyama
Kyrgyz

Ladin

Ladino

Lahnda
Lakota

Lao

Latin

Latvian

Laz

Lezgian

Limburgish
Lingala

Lithuanian

Livonian

Lombard

Low German/Low Saxon

Luo

Luxembourgish

Maasai/Maa

Macedonian

Maldivian

Maithili

Malagasy

Malay

Malayalam

Maltese

Mandinka

Manipuri

Mansi

Manx

Māori

Marathi

Mari/Cheremis

Marshallese

Menominee
Mirandese

Mohawk

Moksha

Moldovan

Mongolian

Montagnais

Nahuatl

Naskapi

Nauruan

Navajo

Occitan

Oshiwambo

Nepali

Newari

Niuean

Nogai

Noongar

Northern Sotho

Norwegian

Nyamwezi
Nyoro
Ojibwe

O'odham

Odia

Ossetian

Palauan

Pali

Papiamento

Pashto

Persian

Piedmontese

Polish

Portuguese

Punjabi

Quechua

Raga

Rapanui

Rarotongan

Romanian

Romansh

Romani

Rotuman

Russian

Ruthenian

Saami (Inari)

Sámi (Kildin)

Sámi (Lule)

Sámi (North)

Sámi (Pite)

Sámi (Skolt)

Sámi (South)

Sámi (Ter)

Sámi (Ume)

Santali

Samoan

Sango

Sanskrit

Sardinian

Sark Norman
Scots

Scottish Gaelic

Selkup
Serbian

Shavante

Shawnee

Shona

Shor

Sicilian

Sidamo
Silesian

Sindhi

Sinhala

Silt'e

Slovak

Slovenian

Somali

Soninke

Sorbian (Lower)

Sorbian (Upper)

Southern Sotho

South Slavey
Spanish

Sundanese

Svan

Swabish
Swahili

Swati

Swedish

Swiss German

Syriac

Tabassaran

Tagalog

Tahitian

Tai Nüa

Tajik

Tamil

Tatar

Telugu

Tetum

Thai

Tibetan

Tigre

Tigrinya

Tlingit

Tok Pisin

Tonga
Tongan

Tsez

Tsonga

Tswana

Tumbuka

Turkish

Turkmen

Tuscarora

Tuvaluan

Tuvan

Twi

Udmurt

Ukrainian

Urdu

Uyghur

Uzbek

Venda

Venetian

Veps

Vietnamese

Võro

Votic

Walloon

Waray-Waray

Welsh

Wiradjuri

Wolof

Xamtanga

Xhosa

Yagua

Yi

Yiddish

Yindjibarndi

Yolngu

Yoruba

Yupik

Zhuang

Zulu

Zuñi

Comment: As an intern I had to do the same for all 50 states in the United States. It took about 10 minutes. The fastest way you will find to do it is to copy and paste the empty tuples then write the text in. You could have been half done in the time you spent preparing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small python script to do just that.
You would still have to edit some nations which are composed by several words.

```
file_name = "nat.txt"
with open(file_name) as f:
for line in f:
    for word in line.split(" "):
    print "(\'" + word.decode('utf-8').upper().encode('utf-8') +"\', \'" + word +"\'),"
```

it also takes care of unicode characters

and the final list:

```
('AFGHANS', 'Afghans'),
('ALBANIANS', 'Albanians'),
('ALGERIANS', 'Algerians'),
('AMERICANS', 'Americans'),
('ANDORRANS', 'Andorrans'),
('ANGOLANS', 'Angolans'),
('ARGENTINES', 'Argentines'),
('ARMENIANS', 'Armenians'),
('AROMANIANS', 'Aromanians'),
('ARUBANS', 'Arubans'),
('AUSTRALIANS', 'Australians'),
('AUSTRIANS', 'Austrians'),
('AZERBAIJANIS', 'Azerbaijanis'),
('BAHAMIANS', 'Bahamians'),
('BAHRAINIS', 'Bahrainis'),
('BANGLADESHIS', 'Bangladeshis'),
('BARBADIANS', 'Barbadians'),
('BASOTHO', 'Basotho'),
('BASQUES', 'Basques'),
('BELARUSIANS', 'Belarusians'),
('BELGIANS', 'Belgians'),
('BELIZEANS', 'Belizeans'),
('BERMUDIANS', 'Bermudians'),
('BOERS', 'Boers'),
('BOSNIAKS', 'Bosniaks'),
('BRAZILIANS', 'Brazilians'),
('BRETONS', 'Bretons'),
('BRITISH', 'British'),
('BRITISH', 'British'),
('VIRGIN', 'Virgin'),
('ISLANDERS', 'Islanders'),
('BRUNEIANS', 'Bruneians'),
('BULGARIANS', 'Bulgarians'),
('MACEDONIAN', 'Macedonian'),
('BULGARIANS', 'Bulgarians'),
('BURKINABÈS', 'Burkinabès'),
('BURUNDIANS', 'Burundians'),
('CAMBODIANS', 'Cambodians'),
('CAMEROONIANS', 'Cameroonians'),
('CANADIANS', 'Canadians'),
('CATALANS', 'Catalans'),
('CAPE', 'Cape'),
('VERDEANS', 'Verdeans'),
('CHADIANS', 'Chadians'),
('CHILEANS', 'Chileans'),
('CHINESE', 'Chinese'),
('COLOMBIANS', 'Colombians'),
('COMORIANS', 'Comorians'),
('CONGOLESE', 'Congolese'),
('CROATIANS', 'Croatians'),
('CUBANS', 'Cubans'),
('CYPRIOTS', 'Cypriots'),
('TURKISH', 'Turkish'),
('CYPRIOTS', 'Cypriots'),
('CZECHS', 'Czechs'),
('DANES', 'Danes'),
('DOMINICANS', 'Dominicans'),
('(REPUBLIC)', '(Republic)'),
('DOMINICANS', 'Dominicans'),
('(COMMONWEALTH)', '(Commonwealth)'),
('DUTCH', 'Dutch'),
('EAST', 'East'),
('TIMORESE', 'Timorese'),
('ECUADORIANS', 'Ecuadorians'),
('EGYPTIANS', 'Egyptians'),
('EMIRATIS', 'Emiratis'),
('ENGLISH', 'English'),
('ERITREANS', 'Eritreans'),
('ESTONIANS', 'Estonians'),
('ETHIOPIANS', 'Ethiopians'),
('FALKLAND', 'Falkland'),
('ISLANDERS', 'Islanders'),
('FAROESE', 'Faroese'),
('FINNS', 'Finns'),
('FINNISH', 'Finnish'),
('SWEDISH', 'Swedish'),
('FIJIANS', 'Fijians'),
('FILIPINOS', 'Filipinos'),
('FRENCH', 'French'),
('CITIZENS', 'citizens'),
('GEORGIANS', 'Georgians'),
('GERMANS', 'Germans'),
('BALTIC', 'Baltic'),
('GERMANS', 'Germans'),
('GHANAIANS', 'Ghanaians'),
('GIBRALTAR', 'Gibraltar'),
('GREEKS', 'Greeks'),
('GREEK', 'Greek'),
('MACEDONIANS', 'Macedonians'),
('GRENADIANS', 'Grenadians'),
('GUATEMALANS', 'Guatemalans'),
('GUIANESE', 'Guianese'),
('(FRENCH)', '(French)'),
('GUINEANS', 'Guineans'),
('GUINEA-BISSAU', 'Guinea-Bissau'),
('NATIONALS', 'nationals'),
('GUYANESE', 'Guyanese'),
('HAITIANS', 'Haitians'),
('HONDURANS', 'Hondurans'),
('HONG', 'Hong'),
('KONG', 'Kong'),
('HUNGARIANS', 'Hungarians'),
('ICELANDERS', 'Icelanders'),
('I-KIRIBATI', 'I-Kiribati'),
('INDIANS', 'Indians'),
('INDONESIANS', 'Indonesians'),
('IRANIANS', 'Iranians'),
('IRAQIS', 'Iraqis'),
('IRISH', 'Irish'),
('ISRAELIS', 'Israelis'),
('ITALIANS', 'Italians'),
('IVOIRIANS', 'Ivoirians'),
('JAMAICANS', 'Jamaicans'),
('JAPANESE', 'Japanese'),
('JORDANIANS', 'Jordanians'),
('KAZAKHS', 'Kazakhs'),
('KENYANS', 'Kenyans'),
('KOREANS', 'Koreans'),
('KOSOVARS', 'Kosovars'),
('KURDS', 'Kurds'),
('KUWAITIS', 'Kuwaitis'),
('KYRGYZS', 'Kyrgyzs'),
('LAO', 'Lao'),
('LATVIANS', 'Latvians'),
('LEBANESE', 'Lebanese'),
('LIBERIANS', 'Liberians'),
('LIBYANS', 'Libyans'),
('LIECHTENSTEINERS', 'Liechtensteiners'),
('LITHUANIANS', 'Lithuanians'),
('LUXEMBOURGERS', 'Luxembourgers'),
('MACAO', 'Macao'),
('MACEDONIANS', 'Macedonians'),
('MALAGASY', 'Malagasy'),
('MALAYSIANS', 'Malaysians'),
('MALAWIANS', 'Malawians'),
('MALDIVIANS', 'Maldivians'),
('MALIANS', 'Malians'),
('MALTESE', 'Maltese'),
('MANX', 'Manx'),
('MAURITIANS', 'Mauritians'),
('MEXICANS', 'Mexicans'),
('MOLDOVANS', 'Moldovans'),
('MOROCCANS', 'Moroccans'),
('MONGOLIANS', 'Mongolians'),
('MONTENEGRINS', 'Montenegrins'),
('NAMIBIANS', 'Namibians'),
('NEPALESE', 'Nepalese'),
('NEW', 'New'),
('ZEALANDERS', 'Zealanders'),
('NICARAGUANS', 'Nicaraguans'),
('NIGERIENS', 'Nigeriens'),
('NIGERIANS', 'Nigerians'),
('NORWEGIANS', 'Norwegians'),
('PAKISTANIS', 'Pakistanis'),
('PALAUANS', 'Palauans'),
('PALESTINIANS', 'Palestinians'),
('PANAMANIANS', 'Panamanians'),
('PAPUA', 'Papua'),
('NEW', 'New'),
('GUINEANS', 'Guineans'),
('PARAGUAYANS', 'Paraguayans'),
('PERUVIANS', 'Peruvians'),
('POLES', 'Poles'),
('PORTUGUESE', 'Portuguese'),
('PUERTO', 'Puerto'),
('RICANS', 'Ricans'),
('QUEBECERS', 'Quebecers'),
('RÉUNIONNAIS', 'Réunionnais'),
('ROMANIANS', 'Romanians'),
('RUSSIANS', 'Russians'),
('BALTIC', 'Baltic'),
('RUSSIANS', 'Russians'),
('RWANDANS', 'Rwandans'),
('SALVADORANS', 'Salvadorans'),
('SÃO', 'São'),
('TOMÉ', 'Tomé'),
('AND', 'and'),
('PRÍNCIPE', 'Príncipe'),
('SAUDIS', 'Saudis'),
('SCOTS', 'Scots'),
('SENEGALESE', 'Senegalese'),
('SERBS', 'Serbs'),
('SIERRA', 'Sierra'),
('LEONEANS', 'Leoneans'),
('SINGAPOREANS', 'Singaporeans'),
('SINDHIAN', 'Sindhian'),
('SLOVAKS', 'Slovaks'),
('SLOVENES', 'Slovenes'),
('SOMALIS', 'Somalis'),
('SOMALILANDERS', 'Somalilanders'),
('SOUTH', 'South'),
('AFRICANS', 'Africans'),
('SPANIARDS', 'Spaniards'),
('SRI', 'Sri'),
('LANKANS', 'Lankans'),
('ST', 'St'),
('LUCIANS', 'Lucians'),
('SUDANESE', 'Sudanese'),
('SURINAMESE', 'Surinamese'),
('SWEDES', 'Swedes'),
('SWISS', 'Swiss'),
('SYRIACS', 'Syriacs'),
('SYRIANS', 'Syrians'),
('TAJIK', 'Tajik'),
('TAIWANESE', 'Taiwanese'),
('TANZANIANS', 'Tanzanians'),
('THAIS', 'Thais'),
('TIBETANS', 'Tibetans'),
('TOBAGONIANS', 'Tobagonians'),
('TRINIDADIANS', 'Trinidadians'),
('TUNISIANS', 'Tunisians'),
('TURKS', 'Turks'),
('TUVALUANS', 'Tuvaluans'),
('UGANDANS', 'Ugandans'),
('UKRAINIANS', 'Ukrainians'),
('URUGUAYANS', 'Uruguayans'),
('UZBEKS', 'Uzbeks'),
('VANUATUANS', 'Vanuatuans'),
('VENEZUELANS', 'Venezuelans'),
('VIETNAMESE', 'Vietnamese'),
('WELSH', 'Welsh'),
('YEMENIS', 'Yemenis'),
('ZAMBIANS', 'Zambians'),
('ZIMBABWEANS', 'Zimbabweans'),
('ASSYRIANS', 'Assyrians'),
('AZERIS', 'Azeris'),
('BASQUES', 'Basques'),
('BENGALIS', 'Bengalis'),
('BERBERS', 'Berbers'),
('BOERS', 'Boers'),
('BURYATS', 'Buryats'),
('CAJUNS', 'Cajuns'),
('CATALANS', 'Catalans'),
('CELTS', 'Celts'),
('CHUVASH', 'Chuvash'),
('GREEKS', 'Greeks'),
('HAN', 'Han'),
('CHINESE', 'Chinese'),
('HISPANIC', 'Hispanic'),
('AND', 'and'),
('LATINO', 'Latino'),
('AMERICANS', 'Americans'),
('HUTUS', 'Hutus'),
('IGBO', 'Igbo'),
('INDIGENOUS', 'Indigenous'),
('AUSTRALIANS', 'Australians'),
('INDIGENOUS', 'Indigenous'),
('PEOPLE', 'people'),
('OF', 'of'),
('THE', 'the'),
('AMERICAS', 'Americas'),
('FIRST', 'First'),
('NATIONS', 'Nations'),
('HUAORANI', 'Huaorani'),
('PEOPLE', 'people'),
('INUIT', 'Inuit'),
('CANADIAN', 'Canadian'),
('INUIT', 'Inuit'),
('GREENLANDIC', 'Greenlandic'),
('INUIT', 'Inuit'),
('MÉTIS', 'Métis'),
('PEOPLE', 'people'),
('NATIVE', 'Native'),
('AMERICANS', 'Americans'),
('JAPANESE', 'Japanese'),
('KAREN', 'Karen'),
('KODAVAS', 'Kodavas'),
('KURDS', 'Kurds'),
('MACEDONIANS', 'Macedonians'),
('MALAYS', 'Malays'),
('MONGOLIANS', 'Mongolians'),
('ROMA', 'Roma'),
('SAMIS', 'Samis'),
('SIKHS', 'Sikhs'),
('SILESIANS', 'Silesians'),
('SINHALESE', 'Sinhalese'),
('SYRIACS', 'Syriacs'),
('KANNADIGAS', 'Kannadigas'),
('TAMILS', 'Tamils'),
('TATARS', 'Tatars'),
('TUTSIS', 'Tutsis'),
('ZULUS', 'Zulus'),
```

Edit:

for languages you can use this:

```
file_name = "languages.txt"  #each word on a separate line
with open(file_name) as f:
for line in f:
    for word in line:
        print "(\'" + word.decode('utf-8').upper().encode('utf-8') +"\', \'" + word +"\'),"
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes about 30 seconds to do with an editor like sublime that supports multi line editing. You may want to manually edit some of the nationalities that have an accent character.

```
("AFGHANS", "Afghans"),
("ALBANIANS", "Albanians"),
("ALGERIANS", "Algerians"),
("AMERICANS", "Americans"),
("ANDORRANS", "Andorrans"),
("ANGOLANS", "Angolans"),
("ARGENTINES", "Argentines"),
("ARMENIANS", "Armenians"),
("AROMANIANS", "Aromanians"),
("ARUBANS", "Arubans"),
("AUSTRALIANS", "Australians"),
("AUSTRIANS", "Austrians"),
("AZERBAIJANIS", "Azerbaijanis"),
("BAHAMIANS", "Bahamians"),
("BAHRAINIS", "Bahrainis"),
("BANGLADESHIS", "Bangladeshis"),
("BARBADIANS", "Barbadians"),
("BASOTHO", "Basotho"),
("BASQUES", "Basques"),
("BELARUSIANS", "Belarusians"),
("BELGIANS", "Belgians"),
("BELIZEANS", "Belizeans"),
("BERMUDIANS", "Bermudians"),
("BOERS", "Boers"),
("BOSNIAKS", "Bosniaks"),
("BRAZILIANS", "Brazilians"),
("BRETONS", "Bretons"),
("BRITISH", "British"),
("BRITISH", "British"),
("VIRGIN", "Virgin"),
("ISLANDERS", "Islanders"),
("BRUNEIANS", "Bruneians"),
("BULGARIANS", "Bulgarians"),
("MACEDONIAN", "Macedonian"),
("BULGARIANS", "Bulgarians"),
("BURKINABÈS", "Burkinabès"),
("BURUNDIANS", "Burundians"),
("CAMBODIANS", "Cambodians"),
("CAMEROONIANS", "Cameroonians"),
("CANADIANS", "Canadians"),
("CATALANS", "Catalans"),
("CAPE", "Cape"),
("VERDEANS", "Verdeans"),
("CHADIANS", "Chadians"),
("CHILEANS", "Chileans"),
("CHINESE", "Chinese"),
("COLOMBIANS", "Colombians"),
("COMORIANS", "Comorians"),
("CONGOLESE", "Congolese"),
("CROATIANS", "Croatians"),
("CUBANS", "Cubans"),
("CYPRIOTS", "Cypriots"),
("TURKISH", "Turkish"),
("CYPRIOTS", "Cypriots"),
("CZECHS", "Czechs"),
("DANES", "Danes"),
("DOMINICANS", "Dominicans"),
(("REPUBLIC", "(Republic)"),)
("DOMINICANS", "Dominicans"),
(("COMMONWEALTH", "(Commonwealth)"),)
("DUTCH", "Dutch"),
("EAST", "East"),
("TIMORESE", "Timorese"),
("ECUADORIANS", "Ecuadorians"),
("EGYPTIANS", "Egyptians"),
("EMIRATIS", "Emiratis"),
("ENGLISH", "English"),
("ERITREANS", "Eritreans"),
("ESTONIANS", "Estonians"),
("ETHIOPIANS", "Ethiopians"),
("FALKLAND", "Falkland"),
("ISLANDERS", "Islanders"),
("FAROESE", "Faroese"),
("FINNS", "Finns"),
("FINNISH", "Finnish"),
("SWEDISH", "Swedish"),
("FIJIANS", "Fijians"),
("FILIPINOS", "Filipinos"),
("FRENCH", "French"),
("CITIZENS", "citizens"),
("GEORGIANS", "Georgians"),
("GERMANS", "Germans"),
("BALTIC", "Baltic"),
("GERMANS", "Germans"),
("GHANAIANS", "Ghanaians"),
("GIBRALTAR", "Gibraltar"),
("GREEKS", "Greeks"),
("GREEK", "Greek"),
("MACEDONIANS", "Macedonians"),
("GRENADIANS", "Grenadians"),
("GUATEMALANS", "Guatemalans"),
("GUIANESE", "Guianese"),
(("FRENCH", "(French)"),)
("GUINEANS", "Guineans"),
(Guinea-"BISSAU", "Guinea-Bissau"),
("NATIONALS", "nationals"),
("GUYANESE", "Guyanese"),
("HAITIANS", "Haitians"),
("HONDURANS", "Hondurans"),
("HONG", "Hong"),
("KONG", "Kong"),
("HUNGARIANS", "Hungarians"),
("ICELANDERS", "Icelanders"),
(I-"KIRIBATI", "I-Kiribati"),
("INDIANS", "Indians"),
("INDONESIANS", "Indonesians"),
("IRANIANS", "Iranians"),
("IRAQIS", "Iraqis"),
("IRISH", "Irish"),
("ISRAELIS", "Israelis"),
("ITALIANS", "Italians"),
("IVOIRIANS", "Ivoirians"),
("JAMAICANS", "Jamaicans"),
("JAPANESE", "Japanese"),
("JORDANIANS", "Jordanians"),
("KAZAKHS", "Kazakhs"),
("KENYANS", "Kenyans"),
("KOREANS", "Koreans"),
("KOSOVARS", "Kosovars"),
("KURDS", "Kurds"),
("KUWAITIS", "Kuwaitis"),
("KYRGYZS", "Kyrgyzs"),
("LAO", "Lao"),
("LATVIANS", "Latvians"),
("LEBANESE", "Lebanese"),
("LIBERIANS", "Liberians"),
("LIBYANS", "Libyans"),
("LIECHTENSTEINERS", "Liechtensteiners"),
("LITHUANIANS", "Lithuanians"),
("LUXEMBOURGERS", "Luxembourgers"),
("MACAO", "Macao"),
("MACEDONIANS", "Macedonians"),
("MALAGASY", "Malagasy"),
("MALAYSIANS", "Malaysians"),
("MALAWIANS", "Malawians"),
("MALDIVIANS", "Maldivians"),
("MALIANS", "Malians"),
("MALTESE", "Maltese"),
("MANX", "Manx"),
("MAURITIANS", "Mauritians"),
("MEXICANS", "Mexicans"),
("MOLDOVANS", "Moldovans"),
("MOROCCANS", "Moroccans"),
("MONGOLIANS", "Mongolians"),
("MONTENEGRINS", "Montenegrins"),
("NAMIBIANS", "Namibians"),
("NEPALESE", "Nepalese"),
("NEW", "New"),
("ZEALANDERS", "Zealanders"),
("NICARAGUANS", "Nicaraguans"),
("NIGERIENS", "Nigeriens"),
("NIGERIANS", "Nigerians"),
("NORWEGIANS", "Norwegians"),
("PAKISTANIS", "Pakistanis"),
("PALAUANS", "Palauans"),
("PALESTINIANS", "Palestinians"),
("PANAMANIANS", "Panamanians"),
("PAPUA", "Papua"),
("NEW", "New"),
("GUINEANS", "Guineans"),
("PARAGUAYANS", "Paraguayans"),
("PERUVIANS", "Peruvians"),
("POLES", "Poles"),
("PORTUGUESE", "Portuguese"),
("PUERTO", "Puerto"),
("RICANS", "Ricans"),
("QUEBECERS", "Quebecers"),
("RÉUNIONNAIS", "Réunionnais"),
("ROMANIANS", "Romanians"),
("RUSSIANS", "Russians"),
("BALTIC", "Baltic"),
("RUSSIANS", "Russians"),
("RWANDANS", "Rwandans"),
("SALVADORANS", "Salvadorans"),
("SÃO", "São"),
("TOMÉ", "Tomé"),
("AND", "and"),
("PRÍNCIPE", "Príncipe"),
("SAUDIS", "Saudis"),
("SCOTS", "Scots"),
("SENEGALESE", "Senegalese"),
("SERBS", "Serbs"),
("SIERRA", "Sierra"),
("LEONEANS", "Leoneans"),
("SINGAPOREANS", "Singaporeans"),
("SINDHIAN", "Sindhian"),
("SLOVAKS", "Slovaks"),
("SLOVENES", "Slovenes"),
("SOMALIS", "Somalis"),
("SOMALILANDERS", "Somalilanders"),
("SOUTH", "South"),
("AFRICANS", "Africans"),
("SPANIARDS", "Spaniards"),
("SRI", "Sri"),
("LANKANS", "Lankans"),
("ST", "St"),
("LUCIANS", "Lucians"),
("SUDANESE", "Sudanese"),
("SURINAMESE", "Surinamese"),
("SWEDES", "Swedes"),
("SWISS", "Swiss"),
("SYRIACS", "Syriacs"),
("SYRIANS", "Syrians"),
("TAJIK", "Tajik"),
("TAIWANESE", "Taiwanese"),
("TANZANIANS", "Tanzanians"),
("THAIS", "Thais"),
("TIBETANS", "Tibetans"),
("TOBAGONIANS", "Tobagonians"),
("TRINIDADIANS", "Trinidadians"),
("TUNISIANS", "Tunisians"),
("TURKS", "Turks"),
("TUVALUANS", "Tuvaluans"),
("UGANDANS", "Ugandans"),
("UKRAINIANS", "Ukrainians"),
("URUGUAYANS", "Uruguayans"),
("UZBEKS", "Uzbeks"),
("VANUATUANS", "Vanuatuans"),
("VENEZUELANS", "Venezuelans"),
("VIETNAMESE", "Vietnamese"),
("WELSH", "Welsh"),
("YEMENIS", "Yemenis"),
("ZAMBIANS", "Zambians"),
("ZIMBABWEANS", "Zimbabweans"),
("ASSYRIANS", "Assyrians"),
("AZERIS", "Azeris"),
("BASQUES", "Basques"),
("BENGALIS", "Bengalis"),
("BERBERS", "Berbers"),
("BOERS", "Boers"),
("BURYATS", "Buryats"),
("CAJUNS", "Cajuns"),
("CATALANS", "Catalans"),
("CELTS", "Celts"),
("CHUVASH", "Chuvash"),
("GREEKS", "Greeks"),
("HAN", "Han"),
("CHINESE", "Chinese"),
("HISPANIC", "Hispanic"),
("AND", "and"),
("LATINO", "Latino"),
("AMERICANS", "Americans"),
("HUTUS", "Hutus"),
("IGBO", "Igbo"),
("INDIGENOUS", "Indigenous"),
("AUSTRALIANS", "Australians"),
("INDIGENOUS", "Indigenous"),
("PEOPLE", "people"),
("OF", "of"),
("THE", "the"),
("AMERICAS", "Americas"),
("FIRST", "First"),
("NATIONS", "Nations"),
("HUAORANI", "Huaorani"),
("PEOPLE", "people"),
("INUIT", "Inuit"),
("CANADIAN", "Canadian"),
("INUIT", "Inuit"),
("GREENLANDIC", "Greenlandic"),
("INUIT", "Inuit"),
("MÉTIS", "Métis"),
("PEOPLE", "people"),
("NATIVE", "Native"),
("AMERICANS", "Americans"),
("JAPANESE", "Japanese"),
("KAREN", "Karen"),
("KODAVAS", "Kodavas"),
("KURDS", "Kurds"),
("MACEDONIANS", "Macedonians"),
("MALAYS", "Malays"),
("MONGOLIANS", "Mongolians"),
("ROMA", "Roma"),
("SAMIS", "Samis"),
("SIKHS", "Sikhs"),
("SILESIANS", "Silesians"),
("SINHALESE", "Sinhalese"),
("SYRIACS", "Syriacs"),
("KANNADIGAS", "Kannadigas"),
("TAMILS", "Tamils"),
("TATARS", "Tatars"),
("TUTSIS", "Tutsis"),
("ZULUS", "Zulus"),
```